# My custom function Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed "My custom function" but in my code, there was an error and I deleted plugin from public_html/wp-content/plugins. When trying to install it again appears error -> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error. How to delete content permanently.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/inc/php/functional.php(103) : eval()'d code:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/inc/php/functional.php(103): eval() #1 /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/inc/php/functional.php(114): spacexchimp_p001_exec() #2 /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/my-custom-functions.php(102): require_once('/home/c/cc47529...') #3 /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2255): include('/home/c/cc47529...') #4 /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-admin/plugins.php(177): plugin_sandbox_scrape(Array) #5 {main} thrown in /home/c/cc47529/wordpress_3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-functions/inc/php/functional.php(103) : eval()'d code on line 23

this is a code of function.php 103 line

```
 // Parsing and execute by Eval
if ( false === @eval( $data ) ) {
    update_option( $plugin['settings'] . '_error', '1' );   // ERROR
    return;   // EXIT
} else {
    update_option( $plugin['settings'] . '_error', '0' );   // RESET ERROR VALUE
}
```

Comment: Have you checked you `error log` for more details on what caused the error?

Comment: I have updated the post